# VSTO Outlook: Detect when a message is moved from a folder to another

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

Is there any way to know when a message is moved from a folder to another in the explorer view? Some event I can handle?

I need to do some things just when a message is moved from one folder to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the `ItemAdd` event on the target folder where items are moved.

Also you may find the [Folder.BeforeItemMove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.beforeitemmove) event helpful. It is fired when an item is about to be moved or deleted from a folder, either as a result of user action or through program code.

Comment: yeap, i have just found that i can subscribe to two events: You can handle that operation from two sides: 1) you can intercept the BeforeItemMove event of the Items collection of the folder *from* which the items are moved and 2) you can intercept the ItemAdd event of the Items collection of the folder *to* which the items are moved. But in both cases i don't know how to subscribe them and when. could you put a little code snippet please?

Comment: There are several approaches: 1. you subscribe to each folder going recursively through the tree of folders 2. handling the `FolderChange` event you can subsribe to the currently selected folder in the Explorer window.

Comment: I am interested in the first option, going recursively through the tree of folders since user can move it to any of the existing folders. How to recursively can I subscribe to ItemAdd for all existing folders?

Comment: Make sense, you need to iterate over the tree of folders recursively and subscribe to the event.

Comment: See [Enumerate folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-enumerate-folders) for the sample code.

Comment: Okay thanks for the code snippet. In that sample code, within the foreach loop, i am trying to subscribe to ItemAdd for each folder by doing: childFolder.ItemAdd += this.ItemAdd; but ItemAdd event does not exist so I cannot subscribe to it. I can see BeforeItemMove but i am interested better once item has been moved to the target folder, so ItemAdd. How can I subscribe to ItemAdd?

Comment: `childFolder.Items.ItemAdd`

Comment: Be aware, the source object (an instance of the `Items` class) should be alive to receive events.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by the source object? Within the loop I do: childFolder.Items.ItemAdd += FolderItems_ItemAdd; and that's all but seems the event is not fired once item is moved to the target folder, so sure i am doing something wrong. Maybe the source object is not alive?

Comment: How can I make source object to be alive for all the folders i am interested in?

Comment: You need to declare the source object at the global scope to make sure it is alive all the time you need to receive events.

Comment: The post is answered. Don't forget to mark the answer and ask separate questions in new threads, so readers could easily recognize questions and answers.

Comment: Okay, see my new post for the issue I have: ItemAdd event not being fired: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73317779/1624552

Comment: The problem with the approach of iterate over the tree of folders recursively and subscribe to events Items.ItemAdd and Folder.BeforeItemMove is that you subscribe to these events at add-in startup but what happens if later the user rename the folder or move the folder inside another one? It will then not work, right?

Comment: You should keep getting events if Items instances are alive.

Comment: Then if you rename folders and move them after you subscribe to those events, they will continue firing? Outlook automatically updates the references/instances you have alive in your collections? This is not what I have seen, I did that, I rename folder but I see that my folder instances I have in the collections were not updated with the new folder name.