# VSTO Outlook ItemAdd not being fired when moving an item to the target folder

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I am trying to do some things on ItemAdd event when an item has been moved to a target folder but ItemAdd event is not firing.

I have declared the source object (the global list MyOlItemsLst) at the global scope to make sure it is alive all the time I need to receive events.

I have wrapped the functionality I want to use inside a MyOutlookItems class, a Folder object and the correspondent event handler which is passed as parameter because I want to process the event in the source class and not in the the wrapped class.

Wrapped class MyOutlookItems:

```
public class MyOutlookItems
{
    public Outlook.MAPIFolder Folder { get; set; }

    private Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler _itemAddEvtHandler;

    public void Subscribe(Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler itemAddEvtHandler)
    {
            _itemAddEvtHandler = itemAddEvtHandler;
            this.Folder.Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(itemAddEvtHandler);
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
            this.Folder.Items.ItemAdd -= new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(_itemAddEvtHandler);
    }
}
```

And in the source class I have below code. The source class is where I subscribe to ItemAdd event and maintain there a list (MyOlItemsList) alive. As you can see i use recursion to subscribe to ItemAdd event for all the folders in all the stores because user can move an item to any folder (it is possible the user has more than one account configured in Outlook).

```
    System.Collections.Generic.List<MyOutlookItems> MyOlItemsLst = new System.Collections.Generic.List<MyOutlookItems>();

    private void SubscribeToItemAdd()
    {
        Outlook.Application application = null;
        Outlook.NameSpace session = null;

        application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        session = application.Session;

        // Iterate over all configured accounts, may be more than one
        Outlook.Stores stores = session.Stores;
        foreach (Outlook.Store store in stores)
        {
            Outlook.Folder root = store.GetRootFolder() as Outlook.Folder;
            EnumerateFolders(root);
        }
    }
    
    private void UnsubscribeFromItemAdd()
    {
        foreach (OutlookItems oli in this.MyOlItemsLst)
        {
            oli.Unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    // Uses recursion to enumerate Outlook subfolders.
    private void EnumerateFolders(Outlook.Folder folder)
    {
        Outlook.Folders childFolders = folder.Folders;
        if (childFolders.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Outlook.Folder childFolder in childFolders)
            {
                MyOutlookItems oli = new MyOutlookItems();
                oli.Folder = childFolder;
                oli.Subscribe(FolderItems_ItemAdd);
                MyOlItemsLst.Add(oli);

                // Call EnumerateFolders using childFolder.
                EnumerateFolders(childFolder);
            }
        }
    }

    private void FolderItems_ItemAdd(object Item)
    {
        // Process the ItemAdd event here
    }
```

For some reason ItemAdd event is not fired so FolderItems_ItemAdd is not called.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an instance of the `Items` class at the class level, not a `Folder` instance. So, instead of the following line of code:

```
 this.Folder.Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(itemAddEvtHandler);
```

You need to have something like that:

```
 public Outlook.Items FolderItems { get; set; }
 this.FolderItems.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(itemAddEvtHandler);
```